# Javascript | addOnEventListener not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

seems like I follow guide after guide and I just don't seem to get the same results, which is quite frustrating...

this is my index.js

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397704
// To debug code on page load in cordova-simulate or on Android devices/emulators: launch your app, set breakpoints, 
// and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready');
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');




    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };

    var openClose = document.getElementById('buttMain').addEventListener("click", menuBar());
    function menuBar() {
        var buttF, buttE, buttX;
        buttF = document.getElementById('ButtF')
        buttX = document.getElementById('ButtX')
        buttE = document.getElementById('ButtE')

        if (openClose.value == 'Open') {
            openClose.value = 'Close';
            buttF.style.visibility = 'visible';
            buttX.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
            buttE.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
        }
        if (openClose.value == 'Close') {
            openClose.value = 'Open';
            buttF.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            buttX.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            buttE.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        }
    };


})();
```

and this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>ADHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="buttMain" value="Open" class="buttonMain">
        <button id="ButtF" class="buttons">Flower</button>
        <button id="ButtX" class="buttons">Extracts</button>
        <button id="ButtE" class="buttons">Edibles</button>
        <div id="mainPage"class="menuPage">
            <h2 id="Menupage" class="titles">Flower Menu Feed!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="app">
            <h1 class="colorchange">American Harvest</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Open Menu</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess i'm not fully grasping how this is all working?? I mean I create the objects of each button my javascript, than I try to set them either to visible or hidden, Not a tough script if you ask me... I even want it to change the value of the button I am clicking!! Any help is greatly appreciated, as far as documentation goes I don't see where I'm messing up, is my javascript not finding these buttons?? Also When i click the button it does NOTHING!! :D doesn't change the value to change the button text OR change the other buttons to visible or hidden, woot woot!! I just don't quite understand, am I missing a plugin, or... what???

Comment: I also receive this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. And it's referencing the if(openClose.value == 'Open') do I need to make openClose.value a string first??

Comment: You should mark an answer as answered :)

Comment: sorry to sound noob, but how do i change to answered?

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You had some errors in your code. See the snippet which works and has
>   been fixed !
>   Follow the 
>   `//[*Fix*] : ...` 
>   comments for the changes that have been done. You can run the code snippet here itself and check :).

So the main learnings here is, to bind an event listener you have to assign the name! not the 'called' function

```
function doWhenClicked(e){
     console.log('somebody clicked');
}

//This is wrong
someElement.addEventListener('click', doWhenClicked());

//This is correct
someElement.addEventListener('click', doWhenClicked);
```

Also you should separately assign a 'selected' element to a variable. Preferably in an efficient manner in more global scopes.

```js
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397704
// To debug code on page load in cordova-simulate or on Android devices/emulators: launch your app, set breakpoints, 
// and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
(function() {
  "use strict";

  document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready');
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
  };

  function onPause() {
    // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
  };

  function onResume() {
    // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
  };
  
  //[*Fix*] :  Separated selector and event listener addition to two separate statements
  //[*Fix*] :  Added reference to 'menuBar' without calling it ( menuBar() )
  var openClose = document.getElementById('buttMain');
  openClose.addEventListener("click", menuBar);
  
    //[*Fix*] :  Hide buttons by default
  var buttF, buttE, buttX;
  buttF = document.getElementById('ButtF')
  buttX = document.getElementById('ButtX')
  buttE = document.getElementById('ButtE')
  buttF.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  buttX.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  buttE.style.visibility = 'hidden';

  function menuBar() {
    if (openClose.value === 'Open') {
      openClose.value = 'Close';
      buttF.style.visibility = 'visible';
      buttX.style.visibility = 'visible';
      buttE.style.visibility = 'visible';
        //[*Fix*] :  Fix condition here with an else if
    } else if (openClose.value === 'Close') {
      openClose.value = 'Open';
      buttF.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      buttX.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      buttE.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  };


})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <title>ADHP</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="buttMain" value="Open" class="buttonMain">
  <button id="ButtF" class="buttons">Flower</button>
  <button id="ButtX" class="buttons">Extracts</button>
  <button id="ButtE" class="buttons">Edibles</button>
  <div id="mainPage" class="menuPage">
    <h2 id="Menupage" class="titles">Flower Menu Feed!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="app">
    <h1 class="colorchange">American Harvest</h1>
    <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
      <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
      <p class="event received">Open Menu</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you don't pass a function as click listener:

```
addEventListener("click", menuBar())
```

This code will execute `menuBar` right there, not when the event happens. That argument must be a function, so do:

```
addEventListener("click", menuBar)
```

Secondly, you add an event listener at the same time you actually want to assign the element to a variable. But that does not work:

```
var openClose = document.getElementById('buttMain').addEventListener("click", ...
```

Now you actually assigned the return value of `addEventListener` to your variable! That is `undefined`; not your `buttMain` element. So split that up into:

```
var openClose = document.getElementById('buttMain');
openClose.addEventListener("click", menuBar);
```

You are also doing `if (openClose.value == 'Close')` *after* you have set that value in the first `if` block, so you'll have cases where both `if` blocks are executed. Just use an `else`:

```
if (openClose.value == 'Open') {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

As a side note: don't bind functions with `this` when it is not relevant. In the first instance where you do that, `this` is `undefined`, so that is useless. The default would be more useful, i.e. your function will be called with `this` set to the element that triggered the event.

Finally, it can indeed be frustrating to have a script that seems correct, but still does not behave as expected. In such case there is the console for helping out: try to use it to the full. Use break points, inspect variables, ...etc. In this case it could have helped you to spot that `menuBar` was executing too soon.